# Have divs same height with flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a have blocks that I would like to be inline and then have the same height no matter how much text is going to be in the boxes. The amount of text could vary at any point. I have the blocks inline but the height I can not figure out how to have the same height for all of them.

HTML:

```
<div class="article_block">
   <div class="article_block_content">
       <div class="article_block_content_left">
          <img class="article_image" alt="<%= headline %>" title="<%= headline %>" src="<%= media_path %>"/>
        </div>

        <div class="article_block_content_right">
          <h5 class="article-tag"><%= category.name %></h5>
          <h2 class="article-title"><%= headline %></h2>
          <h4 class="article-subtitle">This is the future home of the article headline. I hope this makes you want to read the article.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.article_block {
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-flex;

    .article_block_content{
      margin: 10px;
      height: inherit;

      .article_block_content_left {

      }
      .article_block_content_right {
        padding: 20px;

        .article-tag {
          text-align: center;
          color: #7d8a8f;
          text-transform: capitalize;
          font-size: 14px;
          font-family: 'Open Sans';
          padding-top: 15px;
        }
        .article-title {
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Merriweather';
          color: #333;
        }
        .article-subtitle {
          text-align: center;
          font-family: 'Merriweather';
          font-style: italic;
          color: #464849
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This is currently what is happening
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `display: flex` on the **parent** of your `.article-block` divs. This will keep the three `.article-block` divs to be the same height (because `align-items` default is `stretch`).

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

.article-block-wrap {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.article_block {
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 0 0 33.333%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.article_block_content{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.article_block_content_left {
    text-align: center;
}

.article_block_content_right {
  padding: 20px;
}

.article-tag {
  text-align: center;
  color: #7d8a8f;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  padding-top: 15px;
}

.article-title {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  color: #333;
}

.article-subtitle {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather';
  font-style: italic;
  color: #464849
}
```

```html
<div class="article-block-wrap">

  <div class="article_block">
     <div class="article_block_content">
         <div class="article_block_content_left">
            <img class="article_image" src="https://placekitten.com/150/275"/>
          </div>

          <div class="article_block_content_right">
            <h5 class="article-tag">Category Name</h5>
            <h2 class="article-title">This is a long headline</h2>
            <h4 class="article-subtitle">This is the future home of the article headline. I hope this makes you want to read the article.</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article_block">
     <div class="article_block_content">
         <div class="article_block_content_left">
            <img class="article_image" src="https://placekitten.com/150/300"/>
          </div>

          <div class="article_block_content_right">
            <h5 class="article-tag">Category Name</h5>
            <h2 class="article-title">This is a much longer headline than either the first or third block</h2>
            <h4 class="article-subtitle">This is the future home of the article headline. I hope this makes you want to read the article.</h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="article_block">
     <div class="article_block_content">
         <div class="article_block_content_left">
            <img class="article_image" src="https://placekitten.com/150/250"/>
          </div>

          <div class="article_block_content_right">
            <h5 class="article-tag">Category Name</h5>
            <h2 class="article-title">This is a slightly longer headline</h2>
            <h4 class="article-subtitle">
              This is the future home of the article headline. I hope this makes you want to read the article.
              This is the future home of the article headline. I hope this makes you want to read the article.
            </h4>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
     
</div><!-- .article-block-wrap -->
```

Comment: You can remove the incorrect part and leave description about the correct solution only. In my opinion it will be better than current version. :)

Comment: Thank you. When I do this the blocks align at the top, but the colored block still is not the same size. Essentially all this did was vertically align it to the top

Comment: @AndrewC - the blocks are all the same height (as seen by their background color) in my browser. Keep in mind that `flex` (and related properties) needs to be prefixed with `-webkit` or `-ms` in IE/Edge.

Comment: @Adam, ah ok. I can see it now on on codepen with your answer. Though Im still not seeing this on my end, but i grasp the concept. Im guessing maybe some outside styles are effecting it. Thanks for the help!